# CakePHP 2.0 migration XML Helper

Tags: xml, cakephp, migration

Almost finished a CakePHP migration (on a very big project which I didn't write) from 1.3.14 to 2.0.5  One of the remaining issues is with the deprecation of the XML Helper.

The new XML class in 2.0.5 fails for me where it previously worked.  The migration guide states "Now this class does not manipulate data anymore, and it is a wrapper to SimpleXMLElement"
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#xml

Previously I was using:

```
file_put_contents($xml_file, $this->Xml->serialize($quote, array('encoding' => 'UTF-8')));
```

I have tried replacing the above with:

```
$xml =  Xml::build($quote, array(
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'format' => 'attributes'));
```

However all I get is an exception 'XmlException' with message 'Invalid input.'  I've included a sample array below.
Basically the new XML class does not like the array input.  There are several parts of the application that all generate complex XML and they have the same issue.

Has anyone run into this problem?  It will take me forever to debug this.

I guess a potential workaround would be to copy the old Xml.php and helper and maybe make a plugin, but I'd prefer to get this all working if possible.

Sample array:

```
Array
(
    [Quote] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [quote_template_id] => 1
            [project_id] => 1
            [quote_status_id] => 1
            [client_id] => 1
            [date_added] => 2011-05-11
            [is_archived] => 0
            [comment] => Revision 2.
        )

    [Project] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [project_status_id] => 2
            [user_id] => 5
            [salesperson_id] => 5
            [site_id] => 1
            [name] => Test Project
            [description] => 
            [is_archived] => 0
            [date_added] => 2011-05-11
            [expected_start] => 2011-05-11
            [Actual_start] => 
            [expected_finish] => 2011-05-11
            [actual_finish] => 
            [special_clearance] => 1
            [ProjectStatus] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Tendering
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [user_group_id] => 5
                    [username] => operations
                    [password] => 7de1e823411aec881a96475e614d6286b944e92b
                    [first_name] => Operations
                    [last_name] => Person
                    [contact_phone] => 0400 000 000
                    [contact_number] => 0400 000 000
                    [emerg_contact_name] => 123
                    [emerg_contact_phone] => 0400 000 000
                    [is_active] => 1
                    [is_reset_required] => 0
                    [address] => 123
                    [state] => VIC
                    [suburb] => 123
                    [postcode] => 3000
                    [full_name] => Operations Person
                )

            [Site] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [site_type_id] => 1
                    [zone_id] => 1
                    [name] => Highpoint Test Site
                    [address] => 200 Rosamond Road
                    [suburb] => Maribyrnong
                    [postcode] => 3032
                    [state] => VIC
                    [melway_ref] => -
                    [date_added] => 2011-02-25 11:19:00
                    [comment] => This is just a test site
                    [is_active] => 1
                )

            [Salesperson] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [user_group_id] => 5
                    [username] => operations
                    [password] => 7de1e823411aec881a96475e614d6286b944e92b
                    [first_name] => Operations
                    [last_name] => Person
                    [contact_phone] => 0400 000 000
                    [contact_number] => 0400 000 000
                    [emerg_contact_name] => 123
                    [emerg_contact_phone] => 0400 000 000
                    [is_active] => 1
                    [is_reset_required] => 0
                    [address] => 123
                    [state] => VIC
                    [suburb] => 123
                    [postcode] => 3000
                    [full_name] => Operations Person
                )

            [ProjectStatusChange] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [project_id] => 1
                            [project_status_id] => 1
                            [created] => 2011-05-11 17:27:14
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [project_id] => 1
                            [project_status_id] => 2
                            [created] => 2011-05-11 17:27:23
                        )

                )

            [EquipType] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [category_id] => 3
                            [name] => 1-3.5 Tonne Excavator
                            [description] => this is just a test excavator
                            [is_usable_for_cartage] => 0
                            [EquipTypesProject] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [equip_type_id] => 2
                                    [project_id] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [category_id] => 3
                            [name] => Float to Site
                            [description] => 
                            [is_usable_for_cartage] => 0
                            [EquipTypesProject] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [equip_type_id] => 4
                                    [project_id] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

            [MaterialType] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [code] => IB
                            [name] => Clean Brick
                            [is_active] => 1
                            [MaterialTypesProject] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4
                                    [material_type_id] => 6
                                    [project_id] => 1
                                    [is_importable] => 0
                                    [is_exportable] => 0
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 28
                            [code] => C
                            [name] => General Clay
                            [is_active] => 1
                            [MaterialTypesProject] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 5
                                    [material_type_id] => 28
                                    [project_id] => 1
                                    [is_importable] => 0
                                    [is_exportable] => 0
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 38
                            [code] => S
                            [name] => Sand
                            [is_active] => 1
                            [MaterialTypesProject] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 6
                                    [material_type_id] => 38
                                    [project_id] => 1
                                    [is_importable] => 0
                                    [is_exportable] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [QuoteStatus] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Tendering
            [Quote] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [quote_template_id] => 1
                            [project_id] => 1
                            [quote_status_id] => 1
                            [client_id] => 1
                            [date_added] => 2011-05-11
                            [is_archived] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [Revision] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Revision] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [quote_id] => 1
                            [name] => Q-1-3
                            [comment] => Revision 2.
                            [user_id] => 5
                            [revision_time] => 2011-05-11 17:32:55
                            [quote_status_id] => 1
                        )
                )

        )

    [QuoteContact] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [contact_id] => 18
                    [quote_id] => 1
                    [Contact] => Array
                        (
                            [SEQNO] => 18
                            [SALUTATION] => Mr
                            [FIRSTNAME] => Bob
                            [LASTNAME] => Test
                            [TITLE] => Sales
                            [MOBILE] => 
                            [DIRECTPHONE] => 612-9999 9999
                            [DIRECTFAX] => 612-9999 9999
                            [HOMEPHONE] => 
                            [EMAIL] => asdf@asdf.com.au
                            [NOTES] => 
                            [ADDRESS1] => PO BOX 1111
                            [ADDRESS2] => PENRITH
                            [ADDRESS3] => NSW AUSTRALIA
                            [ADDRESS4] => 
                            [DELADDR5] => 
                            [DELADDR6] => 
                            [POST_CODE] =>  
                            [DELADDR1] => 1 CLARKE ST
                            [DELADDR2] => PENRITH
                            [DELADDR3] => SYDNEY
                            [DELADDR4] => AUSTRALIA
                            [ISACTIVE] => Y
                            [ADVERTSOURCE] => 0
                            [SALESNO] => 1
                            [FULLNAME] => Bob Chancellor
                            [COMPANY_ACCNO] => 
                            [COMPANY_ACCTYPE] => 
                            [MSN_ID] => 
                            [YAHOO_ID] => 
                            [SKYPE_ID] => 
                            [ADDRESS5] => 
                            [LAST_UPDATED] => 2010-05-19 16:39:42
                            [id] => 18
                            [name] => Bob Test
                            [email] => asdf@asdf.com.au
                        )

                    [Quote] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [quote_template_id] => 1
                            [project_id] => 1
                            [quote_status_id] => 1
                            [client_id] => 1
                            [date_added] => 2011-05-11
                            [is_archived] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

XML documents must have only one root element, and CakePHP enforces this, ie your array must look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [Root] => Array
        (
            [Quote] => Array
                (
                    ...
                )

            [Project] => Array
                (
                    ...
                )

            ...
        )
)
```

The following should work:

```
$xml = Xml::build(array('root' => $quote), array(
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'format' => 'attributes'
));
```

See also http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html#transforming-an-array-into-a-string-of-xml

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'll give it a whirl and see if it works.  That would mean the Cake 1.3.14 XML class is appending as root element.  I'll take a look at it and see.